# reverse engineer a matrix to get a arbitrary Linear map T

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that it is possible to represent a Linear operator T, when given 2 sets of ordered bases (1 for the domain, 1 for the range), as a Matrix.

Hence I wonder if it is possible for the reverse to happen, when given any $n\times n$, I can cook up an arbitrary Linear operator to represent this matrix.

If no, could I get an explanation.
If yes, how in general should I do it, and can it be generalize to any $n \times m$ matrix ?

Thank you for reading my post, I just started out in linear algebra and hence any help or insights into this is deeply appreciated.

Comment: not so easy to understand your question. you know that $dim(ker) + dim(Im) = dim(\text{whole vector space})$ ? and switching from a linear operator to a matrix is a matter of applying the operator to $e_i$ and computing the inner product with $\tilde{e}_j$, and conversely

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have  $n \times m$ matrix $A$ and you have specified bases $\{v_1,\ldots,v_m\}$ and $\{w_1,\ldots,w_n\}$ for the domain and range respectively.

If you consider the matrix multiplication applied to $(1,0,0,\ldots,0)$ (which represents $v_1$, you get the first column of $A$, which represents a corresponding linear combination of the $w_1,\ldots,w_n$. More generally, the $i$th column of $A$ represents the image of $v_i$, so you can see where each basis vector $v_i$ is sent by the map. By linearity (and the fact that a basis spans the vector space), this completely specifies a linear map.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully understand your questions. Well if you have such that $[T]$ with respect to ordered bases $\alpha$ and $\beta$, then you can derive a general transformation with respect to any vector that can be represented by $\alpha$. The mapping for some $T$ is completely determined by the choice of coefficients for the linear combination of $\alpha$ basis vectors, thus give any vector in $V$ if
$$T: V \rightarrow W$$
You can derive a linear mapping for it. To generalize this result, just derive the linear mappings of the basis vectors of $\alpha$. You already have the transformation matrix so this is trivial to do since:
$$T(a_1\alpha_1 + a_2\alpha_2 + a_3\alpha_3)$$
By linearity of T you can represent this as coefficients of $a_1, ... a_n$ and the coordinate vector columns in $[T]_{\alpha}^{\beta}$. Then depending on your basis and the nature of it, you can generalize the final result to some coordinate vector of $\alpha$ or possibly even better depending on the terms.